# Relation between Cartesian Closed Category and Terminating Programs

Tags: category-theory, lambda-calculus, type-theory

Relation between Cartesian Closed Category and Terminating Programs.

1. Simply Typed Lambda Calculus (STLC) is a Cartesian Closed Category
   (CCC), it has all products, objects that represent arrows and a
   terminal object. Also, STLC is not Turing Complete since all
   computations end (by the Strong Normalization Theorem).
2. Damas-Milner (DM) is a model of STLC with the "let" operator, witch
       alows you to construct non-terminating computations and Turing
       Complete programs (I don't know if the last one is true, I'have never seen
       a proof). That sayed, I think there is no longer a terminal object
       in the "Category of Damas-Milner", because partial computations are
       allowed and there is no unique arrow from all types to some
       hypothetic terminal type.

I would like to know (if known by humanity) if there is any relation between  "non-Turing Complete" typed systems and "Cartesian Closed Categorys".

---

EDIT:

I made a mistake in 2: "the "let" operator, witch alows you to construct non-terminating computations" isn't true. I didn't know that $\lambda f . let\: x\: = f\: x\: in\: x$ is not a typable term in DM. So DM may not allow non-terminating computations.

Also, I found that System-F is strongly normalizing. But that implies HM is strongly normalizing too?

EDIT 2:
"Every term that is well-typed in HM is well-typed in System F. Every well-typed term in System F is SN. Therefore every term that is well-typed in HM is SN. – Gilles" in [link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/why-will-the-hindley-milner-algorithm-never-yield-a-type-like-t1-t2/19431?noredirect=1#comment149882_19431)

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is the Curry–Howard–Lambek correspondence.

Comment: @QthePlatypus is related, but I'm asking a more general question. STLC is one "non-Turing Complete" typed systems. I wanna know if the relation is broad.

Comment: Are you familiar with Moggi's work about computational effect as monads ? I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but it can definitely be a lead: [Computational lambda-calculus and monads](https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/articles/moggi-computational-lambda-calculus-and-monads.pdf)

Comment: @Pece I'm not. I will take a look. Thanks.